# Is the "user environment variables" linked to the Admin account?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

I am deploying a windows 10 PRO image to several laptops by using sysprep and aswer-file. The aswer file create 2 users one admin user (LED) and a second normal user.

In the admin account the "user environment variables" is as below:
[admin variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imspM.png)

It has the Admin name (LED) and also the admin path.

When I go to the other user (not admin) I found the "user environment variables" with the name of the other admin user and with the admin user path. Image below.
Is the "user environment variables" linked by default to the admin user or something is wrong?
[Normal User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9tHb.png)

This because if I am using %AppData% or %USERPROFILE% in the normal user account I'll be redirected to the Admin path.

Comment: [Why have you asked this question again?](https://superuser.com/questions/1559457/appdata-point-to-a-different-user)

Comment: There was not answer on my previous post  and I have received a system message saying my post was not clear suggesting me to write a new one. I hope I didn't create a confusion.

Comment: While your question had received closed votes, the community voted to keep your question open, even if the question was closed you shouldn't be submitting a second question.  You should instead edit your question and clarify it.  **Since you have already deleted your original question, you should improve this question, instead of submitting the question again.**  Submitting the same question, because your question is closed by the community, is not actually allowed.

Comment: sorry if I did not interpret the notifications received in the right way  but I thought the tread was closed and I have to open a new one trying to explain better my case. I 'll really appreciate  if you could suggest me where it needs more details or a better explanation.

Comment: Looking at the timeline your original question was never closed by the community.

Comment: Hi Ramhound  please refer to the image linked here https://ibb.co/wsq2XP6